# Extracting coordinates of a triangulation from DEM data

Tags: dem, tin, graph, usgs, delaunay

I'm working on the succinct representation of planar graphs and now I'm trying to obtain some datasets to test my results. I saw that Delaunay triangulations of elevation data can be a good source of datasets.

I downloaded DEM data from [USGS elevation data](http://viewer.nationalmap.gov/basic/?basemap=b1&category=ned,nedsrc&title=3DEP%20View), but now I don't know how to extract the Delaunay triangulation and (most important for me) its underlying planar graph. Is that even possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited to mathematics stack exchange.

Comment: Hi, I was expecting some hints about QGis or any other GIS software to obtain the triangulation

Comment: DEM data is usually a rectangular grid of height values. Any triangulation from sampled spot heights is probably long gone. You can always sample the DEM yourself at some set of points and construct a triangulation.

Comment: @Spacedman is correct, I am not even sure though you can reverse engineer in this manner.

Comment: Are you wanting a TIN with a subset of points from the DEM?  [This outline](http://ibis.geog.ubc.ca/courses/klink/gis.notes/ncgia/u39.html#SEC39.2) mentions 3 alternative algorithms: Fowler and Little, VIP and Drop Heuristic.

Comment: Not sure why there are votes to close.  I find it neither off-topic nor broad.  Maybe it could be re-phrased to clarify it a bit.  Yeah, it's math - but a sort of math that deals with geography.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution proposed by Spacedman is easy to do with GRASS GIS and Python scripting or or [OpenJump](http://www.openjump.org/)'s "planar graph" command.

1) Generate random points (or specific points) from the DEM and sample elevation at each of these points. ([v.random](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.random.html), [v.drape](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.drape.html))

[image]

2) Compute a TIN with the Delaunay algorithm ([v.delaunay](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.delaunay.html), 3D)

[image]

3) Compute the [Planar Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph) (with Python here): nodes, arcs and faces

Nodes and Arcs:

[image]

Faces

[image]

Comment: Seems like it would be better to pick significant points, such as peaks/valleys, at step 1 instead of random points.  That way the triangular surface would more closely reflect the DEM.

Comment: If you want, it is the principle here: extract points from the DEM